# Implement COMET with PHP

Tags: php, symfony1, comet

I'm looking for examples with COMET (DWR - Direct Web Remoting) in php. I have searched in google & found below url which in quite helpful.

http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

I'm going to implment COMET with symfony. Any body have more examples for this. Experience with Symfony framework?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=comet+php

Answer (score 3):

Using Comet on Apache can prove difficult.

There is a good article on how to use a Comet server alongside Apache on port 80 of your web server here: http://iamseanmurphy.com/2009/03/02/high-performance-comet-on-a-shoestring/

Answer (score 0):

i also did comet by using this link:
http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start
its a good one.here we have to use prototype to implement comet.